# Monitoring a batch file with java

Tags: java, file, process, batch-file

I'm calling a batch that calls another "jar" that send messages to a server and write a report in the end, the time of execution varies from day to day, and the size of the input used in the batch influences to.

I would like to monitor when the batch auto-closes so I can make my original jar to read the log...

I'm calling it like this

```
    Process prog = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\chamados\\corretorRota\\VerificarNumero.bat");
```

and the batch:

```
cd C:\chamados\corretorRota
java -jar BatchDispatcher.jar brux0043 5873 gcpn-rota.txt > resultado.txt
exit
```

(FYI brux0043 = server, 5873 = port gcpn-rota = input file writed previously)
(the batch keeps open util the end of the called jar)

Comment: Shouldn't prog.waitFor() work for you here?

Comment: @Danny write this in an answer to get the rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a log with the timestamp whenever the batch file was executed.

put this line in your batch file

```
echo. |time |find "current" >> log
```

this will then write the timestamp when the batch file was run to the log. Also, there should be a file called log before executing the batch file.

Now your java program can monitor the log and know how many times and when the batch file was executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
prog.waitFor()
```

to wait for the process to finish execution.